# How to get groups belonging to user Cartalyst Sentry 2

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

What is the best way to get the Sentry Groups my `USER` model belongs to in Laravel 4.1?

I couldn't find anything in the docs about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Sentry docs are pretty bare bones. You can do this to get the groups belonging to a user:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

$user->getGroups();

foreach($user->groups as $group)
{
     echo $group->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [sentry docs](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/helpers#getgroups) perform the `getGroups()` Method on the user.